How to configure the Stripe secret in Firebase Cloud Functions?
I'm trying to integrate Stripe into a project of mine, and it looks like I can do it on my cloud functions. I'm following this official guide which tells me to add the API key to my firebase config. However, I don't see any files in my cloud functions project (created with npm) that have to do with Firebase config, and seem to match the syntax.
firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=<YOUR STRIPE SECRET KEY>

What file should I update and where can I find it?

The firebase functions:config:* commands interact with an API (hosted at https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/projects/${projectId}/configs) where the values you provide are stored in your GCP project. They are not stored locally on disk (where they could be accidentally uploaded to git).

The instructions are giving you a Firebase CLI command to run.  That's what this is:
firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=<YOUR STRIPE SECRET KEY>

You run the command with your stripe key instead of the placeholder.
There are no files to edit in this case.
You should keep in mind that the given way of setting config params using functions:config:set is outdated, and you should look into the documentation for different and more secure ways of configuring parameters for your functions.
